# Capture a particular event from child iframe to parent iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent-child

I'm facing a issue where I have to load a particular event from iframe. Say I have a iframe (child) with a alert and onload events, I have to bind the two events to the two buttons in (parent) iframe. Is that possible?
If so ca you suggest me some example which would be so  useful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onloadFunction(){
        alert("Onload for the button");
    }

    function onloadPrompt(){
        prompt("test Prompt");
    }
</script>
<button onclick="onloadPrompt()"> PROMPT</button>
<button onclick="onloadFunction()"> LOAD</button>

</body>
</html>
```

PARENT:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Iframe test
    </title>
</head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.name{
    font-family: monospace;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = $("C:Users/ajay.venkatesh/Desktop/IframeTEst1.html").contents();
    console.log("Iframe working");
    iframe.find('onloadFunction()').click(function(event){
   console.log('work fine');
});
</script>
<body>
<iframe src="C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Desktop\IframeTEst1.html"></iframe>
<h1 class="name"> Ajay Venkatesh</h1>
<button onclick="onloadFunction()"> LOAD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert` is not an event... In any case, you're going to run into CORS issues due to your use of a local file reference for the source of your iframe (which should specify the `file:///` scheme and use forward slashes).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Say consider it has a event. How to capture the particular event to the parent

Comment: Repeating your question will not cause the the problem I outlined in my second sentence to disappear. Use a web server and serve your files from that. There are many free and open source web servers available for Windows.